# Media queries in CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to apply a CSS for tablets. Tablets have larger displays but the pixel density is not as high as on for example the iPhone 4, Samsung Galaxy Nexus etc.

```
<link href="css/mobile-tablet.css" media="all and (min-device-width: 600px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I do that the smartphones will also get that CSS. Is it possible to do this in another way? I don't know if you can check both the number of pixels and the physical width of the screen in centimeters or if there are better ways but.

Comment: In Media Queries inches/centimemters are CSSinches/CSScentimeters. They are _defined_ by the standard, and can be quite different from what you'd measure with a ruler. For example a CSSinch is _defined_ as 96 pixels, and can be only one third of what you'd measure with a ruler. The good part is this means lots of legacy code continues to work. But the not so good part is it also means physical measures like inches or centimeters are at best pretty much useless in Media Queries, and at worst are downright misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these media queries it might help you.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ipad.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iphone.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

Use the range of device width and you can target the devices easily i know there are lot of devices to target but in general you target the devices this way.

Comment: But I am not only targeting iphone/ipads

Comment: I just gave you the example to use device width in media queries, my intention not was to show you the way dedicated for iPhone and iPad, sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can target high pixel-density devices with the min-device-pixel-ratio query like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='highres.css' media='all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width: 600px), all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width: 600px)' />
```

That would target high-res displays with a width over 600px